# Position vector for free fall along an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I understand how to make a force diagram for an inclined plane.

Assuming I have an inclined plane in the form of a right-angled triangle with both cathetes $k$, the angle of the inclined plane is $\tan (k / k) = \tan 1 = 45\deg$.
On top I have an object that glides frictionless down the inclined plane (on the hypotenuse). How can I set up the position vector $\mathbf{r}$ for $x$ and $y$ for the uniformly accelerated movement?

[image]

If the object were to slide down vertically, $\mathbf{r} = (0, k-\frac{1}{2}gt ^ 2)$.

Comment: Where is the origin of your coordinate system? What are the directions of the axes?

Comment: @nasu Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question and added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most convenient coordinate system but any system should do.
You can start with what you know: the displacement along the inclined as a function of time. So just take a point somewhere on the inclined plane. This will be at a distance d from the top of the inclined. The distance d is easy to find from the equation of motion with acceleration $g \sin( \theta) $. Then is just a straightforward geometry problem to find the x and y coordinates of this point. You draw two lines from this point, each parallel to one of the axes. Two smaller triangles will form. Use trigonometry to find k-x and k-y. These will be sides of the small triangles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it, especially the point _distance d is easy to find from the equation of motion with acceleration $g\sin(θ)$_.

Comment: Then your problem is nit just finding the coordinates.  You need to study motion on inclined plane.